# Align Text Widgets In Custom List Tile Vertically In Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am supporting an app for landscape mode in which I want to align Text widgets in my custom List Tile(a container widget), but for some reason the alignment does not match and I get the following output
[image: unaccepted]

The out put I want is as follows

[image: accepted]
I use the following code to display the first output.

```
  Container buildTile(Employee employee) {
    return Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 1),
            boxShadow: [
              //BoxShadow
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.white,
                offset: const Offset(0.0, 0.0),
                blurRadius: 0.0,
                spreadRadius: 0.0,
              ),
            ]),
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.7,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1,
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Container(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  
                children: [
                  Text("ID:${employee.employeeId}",
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 24)),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      Text("Mobile Number:",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20)),
                      Text("${employee.employeePhone}",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal, fontSize: 20))
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.25),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      Text("Name:",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 24)),
                      Text("${employee.employeeName}",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal, fontSize: 24))
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      Text("Weekly Off:",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20)),
                      Text("${employee.employeeWeeklyOff}",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal, fontSize: 20))
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.10),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "${employee.employeeRole}",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 24,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text("    ")
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
```

I tried wrapping the column in alignment widget but that didn't work. When I try to add margin/padding the entire tile contents are shifted.
Please help

Comment: Set individual container Column's crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start. It will align text to left

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In each `column` set `crossAxisAlignment` to `start` like this:

```
Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, // <-- add this
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  
                children: [
                  Text("ID:${employee.employeeId}",
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 24)),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      Text("Mobile Number:",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20)),
                      Text("${employee.employeePhone}",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal, fontSize: 20))
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Widget tree
N.B: it's simple. I didn't make it stylest

```
Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 1),
        boxShadow: const [
          //BoxShadow
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.white,
            offset: const Offset(0.0, 0.0),
            blurRadius: 0.0,
            spreadRadius: 0.0,
          ),
        ]),
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1,
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
    child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 12),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Column(
            children: [
              Text("data"),
              Text("data"),
            ],
          ),
          Spacer(),
          Column(
            children: [
              Text("data"),
              Text("data"),
            ],
          ),
          Spacer(),
          Column(
            children: [
              Text("data"),
              Text("data"),
            ],
          ),
          Spacer(),
          IconButton(onPressed: () {
            
          }, icon: Icon(Icons.edit))
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
```